# How to set up an event with probability of one seventh from coin tossing?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, combinatorics

I have been recently asked in an interview a question that: How to set up an event with probability of one seventh from coin tossing?

I couldn't find the correct answer and still don't know the correct answer yet.

Comment: Could you generate 8 outcomes each with probability 1/8? Why not then just retoss if you got the 8th outcome, so that you only end up with 7 possibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about you toss 3 coins giving the possible events
$$
{TTT,TTH,THT,HTT,HHT,HTH,THH,HHH}
$$

Let event B = not all heads
and event A = All tails

then
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{1*1/8}{7/8}=1/7
$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume they mean fair coins, o/w the answer would be trivial. And, I humbly think that this is a *brain teaser* problem and the hidden question is: write $1/7$ in binary, i.e. $0.0010010...$.

For example, an event with probability $1/4+1/8=3/8=0.011$, can be constructed with the following small events: $\{TTT,TTH,HHH\}$, i.e. what is the probability of having first two tosses as *Tails*, or having first three tosses as *Heads*.

This yields in infinite number of experiments for obtaining $1/7$. But, we can get arbitrarily close. So, achieving $1/7$ is probably (and only) possible under a recursive setting, but that seemed hard for an interview.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2017/01/01/can-you-solve-it-use-a-coin-to-simulate-any-probability-sunday-puzzle/.

Create a game like this:

HHH: you win

TTT: re-toss.

HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH: you lose.

Your probability to win is 1/7.

Using the same method, we can simulate probability of any non-irrational number.

Comment: I like this non-mathematic approach. And the link is useful. Thanks!